# AWS kibana/ES trying to create policy but getting "authorization exception"

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, index-management

I created an AWS ES cluster via terraform, VPC version.
It got me a kibana instance which I can access through a URL.

I access it via a proxy as it is in a VPC and thus not publicly accessible.

All good. But recently I ran out of disk. The infamous Write Status was in red, and nothing was being written into the cluster anymore.
As this is a dev environment. I googled and found the easiest possible to fix this:
`curl -XDELETE <URL>/*`

So far so good, logs are being written again.
But I now thought I need to fix this. So I did some more reading and was wanting to create a Index State Management Policy. I just took the default one and just changed the notification destination.

But when hitting "Create Policy" I get:

> Sorry, there was an error
> Authorization Exception

Which is quite odd as AWS just created a kibana instance with no user management whatsoever - so I would assume to have all rights.

Any idea?

Comment: You do not have all rights and much of the admin-level functionality for ES can not be controlled by the end user with AWS Elasticsearch. With that said, creating an ISM policy should work. I would contact AWS support.

Comment: ok thanks...it's a weird installation with AWS

Answer (score 4):

Indeed we had to ask support and the reason it was failing was that - as this is a dev environment and not production - we had no master nodes and also no UltraWarm storage. The sample strategy I was trying to install moves from hot to warm - which apparently actually means UltraWarm, and thus needs that UltraWarm storage enabled.

A bit of an inappropriate error message though.

Comment: You saved me about a decade of searching!